# C# Trying to mask child values in a dynamic object

Tags: c#, parsing, dynamic, parent-child

At the moment I'm adding functionality to our service that will take in an object that is about to be logged to trace and mask any sensitive fields that are included in the object.

The issue is that we can get objects with different layers. The code I have written so far only handles a parent field and a single child field and uses a nasty embedded for loop implementation to do it.

In the event that we have a third embedded layer of fields in an object we want to log, this wouldn't be able to handle it at all. There has to be a more efficient way of handling generic parsing of a dynamic object, but so far it's managed to avoid me.

The actual code that deserializes and then masks field sin the object looks like this:

```
    private string MaskSensitiveData(string message)
    {
        var maskedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);

        LoggingProperties.GetSensitiveFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < LoggingProperties.Fields.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < LoggingProperties.SubFields.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (maskedMessage[LoggingProperties.Fields[i]] != null)
                {
                    if (maskedMessage[LoggingProperties.Fields[i]][LoggingProperties.SubFields[j]] != null)
                    {
                        maskedMessage[LoggingProperties.Fields[i]][LoggingProperties.SubFields[j]] = MaskField(LoggingProperties.SubFieldLengths[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return maskedMessage.ToString(Formatting.None);
    }
```

And it works off of a LoggingProperties class that looks like this:

```
public static class LoggingProperties
{
    // Constants indicating the number of fields we need to mask at present
    private const int ParentFieldCount = 2;
    private const int SubFieldCount = 4;

    // Constant representing the character we are using for masking
    public const char MaskCharacter = '*';

    // Parent fields array
    public static string[] Fields = new string[ParentFieldCount];
    // Subfields array
    public static string[] SubFields = new string[SubFieldCount];
    // Array of field lengths, each index matching the subfield array elements
    public static int[] SubFieldLengths = new int[SubFieldCount];

    public static void GetSensitiveFields()
    {
        // Sensitive parent fields
        Fields[0] = "Parent1";
        Fields[1] = "Parent2";

        // Sensitive subfields
        SubFields[0] = "Child1";
        SubFields[1] = "Child2";
        SubFields[2] = "Child3";
        SubFields[3] = "Child4";

        // Lengths of sensitive subfields
        SubFieldLengths[0] = 16;
        SubFieldLengths[1] = 16;
        SubFieldLengths[2] = 20;
        SubFieldLengths[3] = 3;
    }
}
```

}

The aim was to have a specific list of fields for the masking method to look out for that could be expanded or contracted along with our systems needs.

The nested loop method though just seems a bit roundabout to me. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here's a small example of a parent and child record that would be in the message prior to the deserialize call. For this example say I'm attempting to mask the currency ID (So in properties the fields could be set like this: Parent1 = "Amounts" and Child1 = "CurrencyId"):

{

```
"Amounts":
{
    "Amount":20.0,
    "CurrencyId":826
}
```

}

An example of a problem would then be if the Amount was divided into pounds and pence:

{

```
"Amounts":
{
    "Amount":
    {
        "Pounds":20,
        "Pence":0
    },
    "CurrencyId":826
}
```

}

This would another layer and yet another embedded for loop...but with that I would be making it overly complex and difficult if the next record in a message had only two layers.

Hope this clarifies a few things =]

Comment: Is the name of the properties to be masked always unique? I mean there is no property that has the same name and is not to be masked, right?

Comment: Yeah, they are unique (or should be...although something has gone horribly wrong as far as I can see if our system gets an object with duplicate fields heh)

Comment: Great. Could you provide a simple example JSON object to be logged please?

Comment: "Amounts":
{
  "Amount": 20.0,
  "CurrencyId": 826
}

Comment: That's an example of a parent field Amounts with those two child fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've really tried but I couldn't figure out an elegant way. Here's what I did:

The first try was using reflection but since all the objects are of type JObject / JToken, I found no way of deciding whether a property is an object or a value.

The second try was (and still is, if you can figure out a good way) more promising: parsing the JSON string into a JObject with `var data = JObject.Parse(message)` and enumerating its properties in a recursive method like this:

```
void Mask(data)
{
    foreach (JToken token in data)
    {
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            // It's an object, mask its children
            Mask(token.Children());
        }
        else 
        {
           // Somehow mask it but I couldn't figure out to do it with JToken
           // Pseudocode, it doesn't actually work:
           if (keysToMask.Contains(token.Name))
               token.Value = "***";
        }
    }
}
```

Since it doesn't work with JTokens, I've tried the same with JProperties and it works for the root object, but there's a problem: although you can see if a given JProperty is an object, you can not select its children object, JProperty.Children() gives JToken again and I found no way to convert it to a JProperty. If anyone knows how to achieve it, please post it.

So the only way I found is a *very* dirty one: using regular expressions. It's all but elegant - but it works.

```
// Make sure the JSON is well formatted
string formattedJson = JObject.Parse(message).ToString();

// Define the keys of the values to be masked
string[] maskedKeys = {"mask1", "mask2"};

// Loop through each key
foreach (var key in maskedKeys)
{
    string original_pattern = string.Format("(\"{0}\": )(\"?[^,\\r\\n]+\"?)", key);
    string masked_pattern = "$1\"censored\"";
    Regex pattern = new Regex(original_pattern);
    formatted_json = pattern.Replace(formatted_json, masked_pattern);
}

// Parse the masked string
var maskedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(formatted_json);
```

Assuming this is your input:

```
{
  "val1"  : "value1",
  "val2"  : "value2",
  "mask1" : "to be masked",
  "prop1" : {
      "val3"  : "value3",
      "val1"  : "value1",
      "mask2" : "to be masked too",
      "prop2" : {
          "val1"  : "value 1 again",
          "mask1" : "this will also get masked"
      }
  }
}
```

This is what you get:

```
{
  "val1": "value1",
  "val2": "value2",
  "mask1": "censored",
  "prop1": {
    "val3": "value3",
    "val1": "value1",
    "mask2": "censored",
    "prop2": {
      "val1": "value 1 again",
      "mask1": "censored"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'll keep working on the second solution as it does look a lot more user friendly but the non-elegant method works fine with different objects being passed into the logger for masking.

Comment: The key step there is to find a way to convert between JToken and JProperty, or get the Name / Value of a JToken. Unfortunately I found no answer to this.

Comment: One thing I'm actually having issues with. Is there a way the regex method can get access to the actual value of mask1? The reason I ask is that our system demands we replace each and every character with an individual * so I will need to know what the length of the value is :/

Comment: On the JToken -> JProperty conversion I'm fighting a losing battle there too -.- heh

Comment: Never mind, sorry man. I managed to get varying length masking in using a foreach looking for matches on the regex and then extracting the length of the Value part of the field.

Comment: Okay, just a hint if you stick with the 2nd solution: you can use JToken.Path to get the path of the token (for the root it's the name of the property, for others it's the full root but you can take the string after the last dot), and use token.Parent[ name of the property] to get/set the token.

Comment: Hmmm. That sounds like it could definitely work. I'll plug it in and let you know how it holds up in our system